# polymer serve with components

Tags: polymer, polymer-1.0, polymer-cli

I have been facing issues with the polymer-cli since I installed it. I am not able to serve components during development. I have to write my own Node.js server with remapping urls to work with components. But the [documentation page](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/tools/polymer-cli#element) clearly suggests that it had already done this work with its own tool.

**What I did**

1. Create a component using polymer-cli's `polymer init`
2. Serve the component using `polymer serve`
3. The result is unexpected and caused the following errors:

Polymer version: *0.18.0-pre.15*

*Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS x64*

### On running `polymer serve`

```
info:    Files in this directory are available under the following URLs
      applications: http://127.0.0.1:8081
      reusable components: http://127.0.0.1:8081/components/test-element/
```

### A) If I try to open `localhost:8081`

```
GET http://localhost:8081/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-loader.js 404 (Not Found)

GET http://localhost:8081/iron-component-page/iron-component-page.html 404 (Not Found)
```

### B) If I try to open `localhost:8081/components/test-element/demo/

The url redirects to `http://localhost:8081/home/user-name/project-root/test-element/`

The index page in the project root directory is served.

```
GET http://localhost:8081/home/user-name/project-root/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-loader.js 

GET http://localhost:8081/home/user-name/project-root/iron-component-page/iron-component-page.html 404 (Not Found)
```

Comment: https://polymer.slack.com/archives/C03PF4L4L/p1490962639349938

Comment: Can you post your bower dependencies? Which version of polymer are you targeting? Your element API: `http://127.0.0.1:8081/components/test-element/` Your element demo: `http://127.0.0.1:8081/components/test-element/demo/index.html` <-- index.html required. Be careful you don't get a file:/// url if editing manually.

Comment: polymer --version gives 0.18.0-pre.15. I'm targeting Polymer 2.0. But I remember facing similar issues with Polymer 1.x.

Comment: It's a project created with polymer init. And, I finished installing all the dependencies it added with bower install. So I am doubtful of where I went wrong.

Comment: It must be in your code somewhere then if the links I posted don't work.

Comment: But the code is created by the polymer-cli itself. So the code cannot be wrong. @JacobPhillips